# Differential equations to eigenvalues, from Strang's textbook

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

I am a little stumped about something in Strangs's (great) textbook "Linear algebra and it's Applications".

At the beginning of chapter 5 (Eigenvalues, page 233) he starts off with an example that connects an eigenvalue problem to systems of differential equations.

$$ \begin{cases}\frac{dv}{dt} = 4v - 5w\\
 \frac{dw}{dt} = 2v - 3w \end{cases}$$

He expresses the probelem as a matrix multiplication, clear.

$$\begin{bmatrix}dv/dt \\ dw/dt\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}4 & -5\\2 & -3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}v \\ w\end{bmatrix}$$

Now this is where things are confusing to me. He expresses the matrix equation using only the symbols (A, u) and then shows us how we would handle the situation if instead of matrices and vectors we had simple scalars, which would be a basic differential equation that leads to a pure exponential solution.

$$\frac{du}{dt} = \mathbf{A} \mathit{u}$$

$$\frac{du}{dt} = cu \to u(t) = e^{at}u_0$$

He then expresses the functions v and w as these pure exponential solutions, I don't understand why he can do this however because the original equations also contained terms with the other variable.

$$\begin{cases}v(t) = e^{\lambda t}y\\ 
u(t) = e^{\lambda t}z\end{cases}$$

He then substitutes the pure exponentials into the original system of equations and from here on out it is pretty clear.

$$\begin{cases}\lambda e^{\lambda t} y = 4e^{\lambda t}y - 5e^{\lambda t}z\\
\lambda e^{\lambda t} z = 2e^{\lambda t}y - 3e^{\lambda t}z\end{cases}$$

My question is basically, how do we get from the original equations to the pure exponentials? Why can the expressions for v(t) and w(t) be made with single terms, while the initial expressions each contain 2 terms?

Comment: Using the left eigenvectors you get $(\dot v-\dot w)=2(v-w)$ and $(2\dot v-5\dot w)=-(2u-5w)$, which can be solved as independent scalar equations. Then recombine.

Comment: I understand enough to carry out the method to solve the system (calculate eigenvectors etc). What I don't understand is how the system is initially converted to the exponential system.

Comment: I do not understand that last comment. From $\dot u=Au$ you get $\ddot u=A\dot u=A^2u$ etc. to $u^{(k)}=A^ku$. Inserting into the Taylor series gives $u(t)=(I+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}A^k)u_0$, and that is the exponential series, $u(t)=\exp(tA)u_0$.

Comment: Basically, how does one get from the initial system of equations to the system that contains the exponential terms?

Comment: You take $u(t)=\exp(At)u_0$ and explore what happens when you express $u_0$ in an eigenbasis of $A$. Eigenspaces of $A$ stay invariant spaces for any analytical expression $f(A)$.

Comment: Ok I will do that. The thing is that the textbook starts the chapter about eigenvectors more or less the way I describe it, without introducing matrices as exponents. I was wondering if I was missing something totally obvious, but Strang sometimes tends to jump through the material.

Comment: This could just be the chain of "intuition" that scalar linear ODE with constant coefficients have solutions in terms of exponentials, so try the same for the system of linear equations. The trial solution $(v(t),w(t))=e^{λt}(y,z)$ with constants $y,z$ leads to the last system, canceling the exponential term leads to the eigensystem as necessary condition for a basis solution of the trial type.